# false result given by JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

Please I want to calculate the period between two dates, i searched and i didn't find  what i need. I have this code :

```
public int getNbjours() {
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date2);
        Period period = new Period(dt1, dt2);
        nbjours=period.getDays();   
           return nbjours;
    }


    public int getNbmois() {
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);
        DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date2);
        Period period = new Period(dt1, dt2);
         nbmois=period.getMonths();

        return nbmois;
    }
```

the problem is somtimes it gives me false results for example :

```
From 2013-05-27 To 2013-06-28 => 1 day and 1 months (it's right here)
From 2013-05-27 To 2013-07-26 => 1 it gives me also 1 day and 1 months and that's false !
From 2013-04-01 To 2013-09-04 => 3 days and 5 months (here it's right)
```

In that false value, typically `27/05` to `26/07` is really `1 month` but not just `1 day`, it's `29 days`
please why it gives me false values ?

Comment: how are you setting date1 and date2?

Comment: by a calendar in JSP. these two methods are in a class and i set the two dates by the constructor.

Comment: Then first you need to isolate the error by testing each step in your process in isolation.

Comment: so i should read the core of the method getDays() of the class Period ...

Comment: i would probably write a test without using JSP. I haven't been working with JSP for several years, but can't it be that there's some constructor magic going on behind the scenes? If that is the case - test that your code works without JSP first. Even better, make a test that proves that Joda time is broken.

Comment: @Souad Try testing those methods in isolation and sww if they work as expected when manually given specific dates.

Comment: I test them out of jsp before. the problem is just the result is sometimes false. so i ask if there is another way to get the right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of `org.joda.time.Period` seems wrong because you are missing the weeks. See this test:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.joda.time.DateMidnight;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DateTimePeriodTest {

    @Test
    public void period1ShouldHaveNoWeeks() {
        final Period period = new Period(new DateMidnight(2013, 5, 27), new DateMidnight(2013, 6, 28));
        assertThat(period.getMonths(), is(1));
        assertThat(period.getWeeks(), is(0));
        assertThat(period.getDays(), is(1));
    }

    @Test
    public void period2ShouldHaveFourWeeks() {
        final Period period = new Period(new DateMidnight(2013, 5, 27), new DateMidnight(2013, 7, 26));
        assertThat(period.getMonths(), is(1));
        assertThat(period.getWeeks(), is(4));
        assertThat(period.getDays(), is(1));
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't find the jar contains this import : **org.junit.Assert.assertThat** . please which jar it is?

Comment: `org.junit.Assert.assertThat(..)` is part of JUnit versions 4.4 and up. For details see [Matchers and assertthat](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Matchers-and-assertthat) of the [JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki).

Comment: thank you but i don't know how to use this class exactly and when put it. i try to instanciate my class where I calculate periods into it and use it like a validator but i don't really know how. :/ should I also create a method to calculate number of weeks in my class ?

Comment: In this case, yes, you need to take weeks into account (and also years!). I suggest you take your time and read carefully though the [*Joda Time* documentation on periods](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html). For example `Days.daysBetween(start, end)` will give you the number of days between start and end. Even with **Joda Time** date and time handling is not trivial.
---
@Souad I didn't mean to baffle you :). The code I uses the form of a program called **unit test** where **assertions** (like `assertThat`) play a major role in showing your application code is correct.

Comment: thank you, so I will calculate also weeks but i get each number (number of weeks,days, months, years) in separated methods. that will be   significan in the result ?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do with the result? What is your use case that requires calculating the period in the first place?

Comment: I have an agent and i want to calculate the period between : Date of statring of his proffesion(job) until the end of it. so i want to know number of years, months and days and i don't want to have somthing like 65 days for example but something like two month and 5 days ...

Comment: Then `Period` is probably right for you. You just need to check all the fields. If you need day resolution, you might use `DateMidnight` or else the `Period` also takes hours, minutes and so on into account.